# The method isNullOrEmpty(String) in the type Strings is not applicable for the arguments (Timestamp)

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem with my report when I put the method isNullOrEmpty(String) in report.
I don't know what is the problem.
 
Anybody know what is the problem?

This is my jrxml file:

```xml
 <jasperReport ....>
    <parameter name="TRUE" isForPrompting="false" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <defaultValueExpression ><![CDATA[new Boolean(true)]]>
        </defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="date_start" isForPrompting="true" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[reports.helpdesk.startDate]]>
        </parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression ><![CDATA[new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()-262800000)]]>
        </defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="date_end" isForPrompting="true" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[reports.helpdesk.endDate]]>
        </parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression ><![CDATA[new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())]]>
        </defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="CENTRIC_DICTIONARY" isForPrompting="false" class="java.util.Map"/>
    <parameter name="SCRIPT_DB_CONNECTION" isForPrompting="false" class="java.sql.Connection"/>
    <field name="enteredby" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="assigned_date" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="max_score" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="totalAnswer" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="totalticketcreated" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="totalfeedbackreceived" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="score" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <background>
        <band height="0"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
        </band>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="0"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="108"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
            <staticText>
                <reportElement
                    x="0"
                    y="0"
                    width="802"
                    height="20"
                    key="staticText"/>
                <box topBorder="None" topBorderColor="#000000" leftBorder="None" leftBorderColor="#000000" rightBorder="None" rightBorderColor="#000000" bottomBorder="None" bottomBorderColor="#000000"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top" rotation="None" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer Feedback by Counter]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                <reportElement
                    x="0"
                    y="20"
                    width="802"
                    height="35"
                    key="textField"
                    isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box topBorder="None" topBorderColor="#000000" leftBorder="None" leftBorderColor="#000000" rightBorder="None" rightBorderColor="#000000" bottomBorder="None" bottomBorderColor="#000000"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top" rotation="None" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[" From ( " + $P{date_start} + " - " + $P{date_start} + " )"]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                <reportElement
                    x="0"
                    y="54"
                    width="802"
                    height="41"
                    key="textField"
                    isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box topBorder="None" topBorderColor="#000000" leftBorder="None" leftBorderColor="#000000" rightBorder="None" rightBorderColor="#000000" bottomBorder="None" bottomBorderColor="#000000"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top" rotation="None" isStyledText="true" lineSpacing="1_1_2">
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty($P{date_start})) ? "Date Ticket Created From : " + $P{date_start} +"\n" + "Date Ticket Created to : " + $P{date_end}
     : "Date Ticket Created From : " + $P{date_start} +"\n" + "Date Ticket Created to : " + $P{date_end}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

UPDATE:-
why the result can't show when i use this formula:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($P{date_start})!= null   &&  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($P{date_end})!=null  && ($P{lookup_department}==null) && ($P{lookup_assignedOfficer}==null) ? "Date Ticket Created From : " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($P{date_start}) +"\n" + "Date Ticket Created to : " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($P{date_end})
:new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($P{date_start})!=null   &&  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($P{date_end})!=null  && ($P{lookup_department}!=null) && ($P{lookup_assignedOfficer}==null) ? "Division :"+$F{division} 
:new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($P{date_start})!=null   &&  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($P{date_end})!=null  && ($P{lookup_department}==null) && ($P{lookup_assignedOfficer}!=null) ? "Ticket Created :"+$F{tickedcreted}
: $F{division}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date_start parameter is a timestamp and the isNullOrEmpty() method apparently expects a String. Try this instead:

```
$P{date_start} != null
```

The entire text field expression becomes:

```
<textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[($P{date_start} != null) ? "Date Ticket Created From : " + $P{date_start} +"\n" + "Date Ticket Created to : " + $P{date_end}
 : "Date Ticket Created From : " + $P{date_start} +"\n" + "Date Ticket Created to : " + $P{date_end}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: i have update my formula. can you see what the problem with my code because im doing what you do but the result is not appear.:(:(:(

Comment: That's too hard to read -- you don't need to check for null on the new SimpleDateFormat, just check if the date is null. But still, it is very difficult to determine what logic you are trying to convey.

Comment: i try but it doesn't show.if you see my first code. i have put the default value.maybe because of that the data got the problem when data just show the is not null data even though i have put the condition null.Any idea?.:(